# TreeView Detect if the user click on Parent or Child node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have TreeView Populating from Database And I am Trying to detect the user action on treeview to make some decision that whether user has clicked on Parent node or Child node or child of a child node.Please any one help me to do this that how can i detect the user action on treeview

Comment: AnyOne Please Answer to the Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
'For Root Node
If YourTreeView.selectedNode.depth=0
'Then Ur Action
elseif 
'For Parent Node
YourTreeView.selectedNode.depth=1
'Then Ur Action
elsif 
'For Leaf Node
YourTreeView.selectedNode.depth > 1
'then Your Action
```

Comment: O Great Really Its Working Thanks A Lot Adeel Aslam

Comment: +1 but its depth not dept !  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.depth(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It's YourTreeView.selectedNode.level=0